# php - print a comma together with an html element

Tags: php, html

I have something like this (in order to print commas):

```
<?php
for(...){
   ?>
   <a href="#">link</a>
   <?php
  if(different than last element){
    echo ",";
  }
}
?>
```

but I get this result:

link , link , link

code:

```
<a href="#">link</a>

,
```

but I want this:

link, link, link

code:

```
<a href="#">link</a>,
```

I tried this:

```
echo preg_replace('#\s+#',',',trim(","));
```

but obviously the problem does not come from the printed comma but in the break line between the html character(the link and the ) and printed comma in php

which is the simple way to fix this? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your link, you have some whitespace before the PHP section starts, and it is actually this whitespace that you are seeing in your output. If you don't want this whitespace, simply write instead:

```
<?php
for(...){
   ?><a href="#">link</a><?php
   if(different than last element){
       echo ",";
   }
}
?>
```

Please note that the `<?php ... ?>` section starts straight after your closing tag `</a>`.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<?php
for(...){
?>
<a href="#">link</a><?php
  if(different than last element){
  echo ",";
}
}
?>
```

I don't think this has anything to do with the echo

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite simple, if you move the opening PHP tag up a line:

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
   ?><a href="#">link</a><?php
  if(1==1){
    echo ",";
  }
}
?>
```

That will work. Alternatively you can do this:

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
   echo "<a href='#'>link</a>";
  if(1==1){
    echo ",";
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use print in **one** php block:

```
<?php
for(...) {
    print("<a href=\"#\">link</a>");
    if(different than last element){
        print(",");
    }
}
print("\n");
?>
```

Or delete the new lines to start a new php block:

```
<?php
for(...){
?><a href="#">link</a><?php
    if(different than last element){
        echo ",";
    }
}
?>
```